# R: plot() uses lines in a scatterplot after as.data.frame()

Tags: r, plot, line

I want to create a simple scatterplot using a table with 2 variables.
The Table looks like this:

```
> freqs
      Var1 Freq
1        1  200
2        2   50
3        3   20
```

I got it using `freqs <- as.data.frame(table(data$V2))` to compute the frequency of numbers in another table.

What I do right now is:

```
plot(freqs, log="xy", main="Frequency of frequencies",
xlab="frequencies", ylab="frequency of frequencies")
```

The problem is, that I get a plot with lines, not dots, and I don't know why.
For another list `plot()` behaved differently and used dots.
It looks like this:

[image]

I know that plot depends on the datatype that it gets. 
So is the problem in the way I generate `freqs`?

Edit:

Here is the data as requested: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9ehtm81zcc8fw0/out-kant.txt?dl=0)

Steps were:

```
data <- read.csv(file="out-kant.txt",head=FALSE,sep="\t")
freqs <- as.data.frame(table(data$V2))
plot(freqs,log="xy",main="Frequency of frequencies", xlab="frequencies", ylab="frequency of frequencies")
```

Comment: can you provide more information so others can reproduce this please. Such as the data used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the type of one of your variables is not set as an integer. You get a scatterplot when both x and y are integers. For example, when you run this code you will get a scatterplot, because it automatically sets both variables as integers:

```
freqs <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='Var1 freq
               1  200
               2  50
               3  20')

plot(freqs, log="xy", main="Frequency of frequencies", xlab="frequencies", ylab="frequency of frequencies")
```

[image]

Check what type your variables are with:

```
typeof(freqs$freq)
typeof(freqs$Var1)
```

Then, if it is not an integer, fix it with:

```
freqs$freq <- as.integer(freqs$freq)
freqs$Var1 <- as.integer(freqs$Var1)
```

EDIT: So I managed to reproduce your issue when I ran:

```
freqs$Var1 <- as.factor(freqs$Var1)
plot(freqs, log="xy", main="Frequency of frequencies", xlab="frequencies", ylab="frequency of frequencies")
```

[image]

Perhaps your Var1 variable is specified as a factor. Try running:

```
freqs$Var1 <- as.numeric(freqs$Var1)
```

EDIT2: Used the above code to make freqs$Var1 numeric on the data provided on the main question's edit, which fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But I checked the variables and they are both integers. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of you data to your original post? That would allow us to take a closer look.

Comment: I uploaded the data. Thanks!

Comment: The edit I made to my solution fixed it when I used your data